# Bind click events for multiple classes with one call

Tags: javascript, jquery

On page load I am binding a lot of `click` events to different objects and code looks like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class1', function() { ... });
$(document).on('click', '.class2', function() { ... });
$(document).on('click', '.class3', function() { ... });
...
```

which I find to look pretty messy. I know that with jQuery one can bind multiple different events on one DOM element:

```
$(document).on({
    click: function() { ... },
    mouseenter: function() { ... },
    mouseleave: function() { ... },
    ...
});
```

Can this be done in a similar way for multiple classes? Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', {
    '.class1': func1,
    '.class2': func2,
    '.class3': func3,
    ...
});
```

Please note, that `func1`, `func2`, `func3`, etc implement different logic and cannot be combined.

Comment: Can't you add an common class to all the divs along with class1, class2...  and attach click handler?

Comment: @Abhi every class has its own logic beyond click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That syntax is not supported by jQuery. You can bind the event handlers by iterating through the object:

```
var handlers = {
  '.class1': function() { ... },
  '.class2': function() { ... },
  '.class3': function() { ... },
};

Object.keys(handlers).forEach(function(sel) {
    $(document).on('click', sel, handlers[sel]);
});
```

You can also define a utility function:

```
/**
 * A utility function for mass event delegation
 * @param  {String|Object} parent - the target of event delegation
 * @param  {String} event - event name
 * @param  {PlainObject} handlers
 * @return {undefined}
 */
$.delegate = function(parent, event, handlers) {
  parent = $(parent);
  Object.keys(handlers).forEach(function(sel) {
    parent.on(event, sel, handlers[sel]);
  });
}

$.delegate(document, 'click', {
  '.class1': function() { ... },
  '.class2': function() { ... },
  '.class3': function() { ... },
});
```